# Detect multiple double-clicks/Reset MouseEvent?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, double-click

I'm trying to write a custom file navigator using `JTables` to navigate the file system.  The issue I'm running into is that the mouse event keeps going as long as you keep pressing the the button, so if someone tries to go up multiple levels by continually double-clicking the "Up One Level" field (since it doesn't move), it only goes back to the one directory unless they stop clicking for an extended period.  As such, I came to the realization that the cause of this is due to the `MouseEvent` still being active.

I'm pretty sure I **could** do what I want simply by doing `if(e.getClickCount() % 2 == 0)` but this feels like an incorrect workaround.  Is there a better/more correct way to do this, such as resetting the `MouseEvent` after the initial double-click?  Is it even possible to reset the `MouseEvent` manually? If so, how?

Edit: Reverted to the all-in-one code to make it easier to copy/paste:

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CreateFrame();
    }
}

class CreateFrame extends JFrame {
    public CreateFrame() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setContentPane(new LocalNavigator());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class LocalTable extends JTable {

        private DefaultTableModel dtm;
        private File path;
        private FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

        public LocalTable() {
            String[] header = new String[] { "Icon", "File/Folder Name", "File Type" };

            dtm = new DefaultTableModel() {
                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                    if (getRowCount() > 0) {
                        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
                    }

                    return super.getColumnClass(column);
                }
            };
            dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
            setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            setRowHeight(25);
            setModel(dtm);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
                        Point p = e.getPoint();
                        int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
                        String type = getValueAt(row, 2).toString().toLowerCase();
                        if (type.contains("root") || type.contains("folder")) {
                            File file = new File((path != null ? path + "/" + getValueAt(row, 1) : getValueAt(row, 1).toString()));
                            if (file != null)
                                repopulateFileFolderList(file);
                        } else if (getValueAt(row, 1).toString().toLowerCase().contains("up one")
                            && getValueAt(row, 2).toString().equals("")) {
                            File file = path.getParentFile();
                            if (file != null)
                                repopulateFileFolderList(file);
                            else
                                getTableRoot();
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Not a directory!");
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void getTableRoot() {
            path = null;
            while (dtm.getRowCount() > 0) {
                dtm.removeRow(0);
            }
            File[] roots = File.listRoots();
            for (File root : roots) {
                dtm.addRow(new Object[] { fsv.getSystemIcon(root), root.getAbsoluteFile(), "Root Directory" });
            }
        }

        private void repopulateFileFolderList(File folder) {
            path = folder;
            while (dtm.getRowCount() > 0) {
                dtm.removeRow(0);
            }
            dtm.addRow(new Object[] { fsv.getSystemIcon(folder), "Up One Level", "" });
            File[] files = folder.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                dtm.addRow(new Object[] { fsv.getSystemIcon(file), file.getName(),
                    (file.isDirectory() ? "Folder" : file.isFile() ? "File" : "Unknown") });
            }
        }
    }

    class LocalNavigator extends JPanel {

        private LocalTable localTable;

        public LocalNavigator() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            localTable = new LocalTable();
            localTable.getTableRoot();

            JScrollPane lTree = new JScrollPane(localTable);

            add(lTree, "Center");

            TableColumnModel columns = localTable.getColumnModel();
            for (int c = 0;c < columns.getColumnCount();c++) {
                if (c == 0)
                    columns.getColumn(c).setMaxWidth(25);
                else
                    columns.getColumn(c).setPreferredWidth(50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I'll do that, thanks. Give me just a moment to edit out the extra junk...

Comment: Created a simple working example and replaced the partial code.

Comment: An MCVE should be one source file (possibly containing more than one class), and include imports..

Comment: Ahh, thank you for clarifying that... I've reverted to my previous example... not as neat and tidy on the web, but I suppose the copy/paste ability makes up for it...

Comment: Might be doing something wrong, but it works for me.  You know, you might have better luck with `JTree` and/or `JXTreeTable` from SwingLabs, SwingX library. See [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: Hmm, so navigating a few folders into the filesystem, then double-clicking the "Up One Level" multiple times back-to-back without pausing between double-clicks (basically just clicking really quick several times in quick succession) works for you?  For me it only works on the first one, then stops since it's still the same `MouseEvent`.  I'll look into that `JXTreeTable` idea, too.  I try to stick with the stock Java libraries as much as possible, but a tree table would be really nice!  I do still wonder if you can manually "reset" the mouse event, prematurely, though.

Comment: As a side note, I tried the `e.consume()`, but it appears to be for a different purpose and/or this event cannot be consumed as it seems to keep triggering on the same event until you stop clicking long enough.  I would assume there is some method you could call or override to reset the event like happens if you pause long enough between clicks, but I'm not overly familiar with the workings of events, under-the-hood, yet.

Answer (score 0):

In your requirements, your explain that you want to allow a double click with a fast delay.
But the `e.getClickCount()==2` you use is not the solution for that because it's limited by your OS configuration.
You can get it by looking the result of  `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval")`

A simple and good way to bypass the problem is that you handle yourself the delay between two clicks in the mouse listener.
You could use a Timer where you can choose the interval max between your clicks and to handle by oneself the count.

The solution is rather simple. So since your code was testable, I modified it directly and i tested. It works for me.
To summarize my modifications, I have added an boolean instance to count the current click count
and have separated the double-click detection (technical) and the double click handling (logic) in two places. It's more readable.
I have chosen 0.5 second as delay max authorized between two clicks.
You can chose another value but if the value is too important (for example one second or more), it can give unexpected double clicks.

```
class CreateFrame extends JFrame {
    ...
   private boolean isAlreadyOneClick;
   ...
   addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (isAlreadyOneClick) {
           handleDoubleClick(e);
           isAlreadyOneClick = false;
        }
        else {
           isAlreadyOneClick = true;
           Timer t = new Timer("doubleclickTimer", false);
           t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               isAlreadyOneClick = false;
            }
           }, 500);
        }

    }

    private void handleDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
        JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
        String type = getValueAt(row, 2).toString().toLowerCase();
        if (type.contains("root") || type.contains("folder")) {
        File file = new File((path != null ? path + "/" + getValueAt(row, 1) : getValueAt(row, 1).toString()));
        if (file != null)
            repopulateFileFolderList(file);
        }
        else if (getValueAt(row, 1).toString().toLowerCase().contains("up one")
            && getValueAt(row, 2).toString().equals("")) {
        File file = path.getParentFile();
        if (file != null)
            repopulateFileFolderList(file);
        else getTableRoot();
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Not a directory!");
        }
    }
    }
```